# Calculating Slope of Dataframe in R

Tags: r

My dataframe looks like this. I've calculated the slope of each point of dataframe. That function is not working on my new notebook . I don't know what to do

```
X1           X2         X3           X4
==========================================================
0.1000000   0.1414214   0.1414214   0.1414214
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1414214   0.1414214   0.1414214   0.1732051
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1414214   0.2449490   0.2645751   0.2645751
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1414214   0.1732051   0.2236068   0.2449490
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1414214   0.1414214   0.1732051   0.1732051
----------------------------------------------------------
0.3316625   0.3464102   0.3605551   0.3741657
----------------------------------------------------------
0.2236068   0.2645751   0.3000000   0.3162278
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1000000   0.1414214   0.1732051   0.2000000
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1414214   0.3000000   0.3162278   0.3464102
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1000000   0.1732051   0.1732051   0.1732051
----------------------------------------------------------


    structure(list(X1 = c(0.1, 0.141421356237309, 0.141421356237309, 
    0.14142135623731, 0.346410161513775), X2 = c(0.14142135623731, 
    0.33166247903554, 0.1, 0.244948974278318, 0.1), X3 = c(0.14142135623731, 
    0.223606797749979, 0.100000000000001, 0.412310562561766, 0.33166247903554
    ), X4 = c(0.14142135623731, 0.0999999999999996, 0.223606797749979, 
    0.360555127546399, 0.141421356237309)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", 
    "X3", "X4"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I was calculating slope like

`d<- apply(data,1, function(x) coef(lm(I(1:4)~x)) )`
but its not working. It generates an error

`Error in model.frame.default(formula = I(1:4) ~ x, drop.unused.levels = TRUE): variable lengths differ (found for 'x')`

Comment: It is working for me using the structure provided

Comment: It is still working on my older notebook. I changed my notebook and its not working on this one

Comment: @Clemsang any idea what I should do??

Comment: Maybe clear your environment, check that code is exactly the same, put the code of your notebook in R file only

Comment: I reinstall R.. Tried R studio. And even tried  Juyptr.. Code is copy paste. But some how I'm facing the issue I'm not expecting at all.

Comment: Please check that you have no `NA` and no factors in `data`

Comment: How to check for that??

Comment: `sum(is.na(data))` and inspect `str(data)`. You can also save `data` in a `rds` file and check that they are identical.

Comment: sum(is.na(data))  returns 0